# Swift -is there a way to trigger a programmatic breakpoint to continue after it stops

Tags: ios, swift, breakpoints

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3646467/4833705) I was able to create a breakpoint in code.

```
func sayHello() {

    raise(SIGTRAP) // programmatic breakpoint
    kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP)  // programmatic breakpoint

    print("say hello")
}
```

Using either of those 2 functions stops execution and "say hello" never gets printed.

The same way I was able to programmatically create the breakpoints is there a way that I can programmatically create something else so that the execution can continue after either of those 2 breakpoints is hit?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do this the right way by having LLDB make a genuine breakpoint? That sort of breakpoint can be very powerful, including proceeding automatically after printing if desired.

Comment: Those aren't breakpoints - You are terminating your app.  You can't continue from that point. Even if you could, what code would be executing to perform the "continue" - You have stopped execution.  What are you trying to do?  You can create breakpoints in Xcode that take some action and automatically continue.

Comment: @Paulw11 oh I didn't know that it terminated the app, the answer to that says it's an "in code" breakpoint (look at it). Thanks for the information. I'm having a problem with an avcapturesession with a fg notification. It only triggers when i put a breakpoint on the bg notification. It's really weird. My idea was just to use a programmatic breakpoint and let it continue. No sure if it'll work but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @matt can you send me a link to with your suggestion?

Comment: Just do it. In the code editor, put a breakpoint, double-click to edit it, tell it to print and continue. It's trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is built in. Here's a breakpoint that prints "here" and continues:

[image]

Comment: quick questions, what happens to break points in apps that are live, do they still trigger or are they ignored? My main concern is if I went live with this will the breakpoint still trigger (I want it to).

Comment: No, breakpoints only execute when running under the debugger.  If you have a timing related issue you need to solve that rather than trying to do something like this

Comment: I agree, I feel like this is an x-y question. You should be concerned about the actual problem, not breakpoints. :)

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for help. I wasn’t sure about breakpoints and a live app. You are correct about this being a bandaid on a broken arm. Luckily I solved problem. Take care!

Comment: @matt this was definitely a temporary fix. I solved the main issue though and was able to push on. Thanks for you help!