# Equivalent of 'int 3' on ARM/iOS processors

Tags: iphone, debugging, assembly

I'm looking for an equivalent of

```
__asm__ int 3
```

for ARM/iOS processors for when I'm debugging on a physical device.  Is it BKPT?  All I want to do is halt the processor so that I can then step past or continue execution at that point like I can with an int 3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to an answer for the question [Breaking into the debugger on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149113/breaking-into-the-debugger-on-iphone) the equivalent is `asm("trap")`. But see the other answers for different techniques.

Especially look into [conditional breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988621/how-to-set-a-conditional-breakpoint-in-xcode-based-on-an-object-string-property) which is a less invasive method.

Comment: For some reason, the linker barfs on not being able to resolve 'asm()'.

Comment: Try `__asm__("trap");` (that's two underscores at each side).

Answer (score 6):

When dealing with macOS ARM:

1. Clang's `__builtin_debugtrap();` function should generate necessary break instruction.
2. If that won't work, try `asm("brk #0x1");`