# How to set breakpoints in Objective-C program in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In vb.net doing debug.assert (false) will set a break point. I can then use this for conditional break point. Say break if a string contain \n

How to do the same for Objective-C programs in Xcode

Comment: Is there a thing like debug.assert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This blog entry](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/break-into-debugger.html) should do the job if you are developping for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [conditional breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988621/how-to-set-a-conditional-breakpoint-in-xcode-based-on-an-object-string-property) if you don't want to/can't modify your code.

To have a breakpoint "in code" see questions that deal with it for [Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37299/xcode-equivalent-of-asm-int-3-debugbreak-halt) and for [iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970841/equivalent-of-int-3-on-arm-ios-processors). They provide the Mac and iOS equivalents of calling `int 3` in Windows (which makes the debugger break at that point).