# How can I trap to the debugger and continue on iOS hardware?

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging, assembly, breakpoints

On Mac OS X and in the iOS simulator (both x86), we can trap to the debugger (LLDB) using the `int3` instruction in inline assembly. This is nice because it traps to a particular line of code but we can continue immediately by hitting continue in the debugger.

Is there a way to do this on iOS hardware?

[An answer to an older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149113/breaking-into-the-debugger-on-iphone) mentions `raise(SIGINT)` which as far as I can see (from examining `signal.h`) does not exist. Another answer mentions the `trap` assembly instruction, which causes a build error ("Unrecognized instruction mnemonic"). Also unrecognized is the `BKPT` assembly instruction [mentioned in ARM documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABHCHGB.html).

I've tried `__builtin_trap()` which almost, almost does what I want, but does not allow me to continue. I keep hitting it unless I advance the instruction pointer manually using `jump +1` or `` register write pc `$pc+8\` ``, which is much less convenient than just hitting continue.

I'm building for iOS 9 for 32- and 64-bit devices using Xcode 7.3.1. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Downvoter, want to explain?

Comment: I guess he downvoted your question because both signal() and SIGINT are part of  standard C. http://opensource.apple.com//source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/sys/signal.h

Comment: raise(SIGINT) can work, but not always reliable, some time it will stop a little bit later, and you need to walk the thread tree to find where is the breakpoint. I once use this solution and then removed. I found later that ASSERT should stop without continue, you should face them instead of ignoring them, why do you want to assert then?

Comment: These types of non-fatal asserts are useful in a lot of cases, such as when code hasn't yet been implemented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple's libc [`signal.h`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1082.20.4/include/signal.h) includes XNU's [`sys/signal.h`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-3248.20.55/bsd/sys/signal.h), which *does* define SIGINT (on all platforms):

```
// [...]

#define SIGHUP  1   /* hangup */
#define SIGINT  2   /* interrupt */
#define SIGQUIT 3   /* quit */
// [...]
```

So while I cannot confirm that this practice does indeed work (due to lack of an iOS 9 device on my part), the barrier that held you back should not actually be a problem.

As for the assembly instructions, `BKPT` is a valid ARM instruction, though only for A32. The A64 variant is called [`BRK`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABHCHGB.html).
If you're building fat binaries and use either of those unconditionally, you will always run into compiler error.

Also note that both instructions require an immediate value (which is passed to the debugger). Omitting that value will produce a compiler error as well.

That said, you should be able to insert debug instructions for A32 and A64 with a simple `#ifdef`:

```
#ifdef __aarch64__
asm volatile("BRK 0");
#else
asm volatile("BKPT 0");
#endif
```

You can substitute `0` by any value of your choosing between `0` and `255`.

A note on the `TRAP` instruction: While Apple's assembler seems to accept this instruction for A32 and translates it to `0xe7ffdefe`, it will issue an "unrecognized instruction mnemonic" on A64, analogous to the `BKPT` instruction.
I was also unable to find any reference to the instruction on the ARM Information Center or in Apple's documentation.

Comment: Some great info here, thanks! Unfortunately BRK/BKPT has the same problem that __builtin_trap() does. I will try SIGINT again and see what happens.

Comment: SIGINT and SIGTRAP do in fact do what I want, although the stack is one level deeper than what I'd prefer. Thanks!

Comment: Happy I was able to help. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20713868) mentions `SVC`, which is the non-debug counterpart to `BKPT`/`BRK` - care to try if `asm("SVC 0")` works any differently than `BKPT`/`BRK`?

Comment: `__LP64__` is probably the wrong macro.  There's an AArch64 ILP32 ABI which still runs in 64-bit mode, just using 32-bit pointers to save cache footprint.  [What predefined macro can I use to detect the target architecture in Clang?](//stackoverflow.com/q/23934862) says `__aarch64__` is the macro you should use.  Should work in at least GCC and clang, hopefully other ARM compilers.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem using Swift on OS X: 
1) `raise(SIGINT)` didn't work for me in background processes (e.g: SceneKit's Scene Renderer Protocol). (perhaps a missing handler?)
2) `__builtin_trap()` doesn't allow continuing after
3) `asm(" int3 ")` requires ObjC and header files, which scared me off at first. But it wasn't too bad. Just added three lines in two new files:

---- NSObject+MachineTrap.h ----

```
void machineTrap(void);
```

---- NSObject+MachineTrap.h ----

```
#import "NSObject+MachineTrap.h"
void machineTrap(void) { asm (" int3 "); } /// Program has TRAPPED to DEBUGGER ///`
```

(My choice of `int3` over say `BRK`, `BKPT`, `SVC` may not be correct.)

Comment: `asm(" int3 ")` is an x86 instruction.  This question is about ARM.  Also, why would you not want the `int3` to inline?  Definite the function as `static inline` in a header and you don't need a `.c`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with ARM based MacBook Pro (Apple M1 chip). This worked for me:

```
asm ("brk #0xF000");
```

This may work with iOS devices too.

Comment: Please provide some explanation.